# Ubuntu won't boot after initializing the Build Environment for Android

Tags: 12.04, boot, nvidia, graphics, desktop-environments

My laptop worked perfectly util I initialized the build environment for Android.
The GUI won't start. It looks like some kinds of graphics card problems.
I tried to fix it but after trying a lot of solutions on the internet nothing worked. (I only know basic linux stuffs.) I've already reinstalled the OS. However, I still want to build the Android from source.

Any idea what might cause the problem? any workaround?

[Here](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#installing-required-packages-ubuntu-1204) is the command that I used to initialize the build environment:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
zip curl libc6-dev libncurses5-dev:i386 x11proto-core-dev \
libx11-dev:i386 libreadline6-dev:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 \
libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32 tofrodos \
python-markdown libxml2-utils xsltproc zlib1g-dev:i386
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

My laptop model is asus u36sd. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Asus_U36SD)
Thanks

Edit:
Base on [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2122554), I guess libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 might cause the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386

The following packages will be REMOVED:
libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal libxatracker1-lts-quantal ubuntu-desktop xorg
xserver-xorg-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-video-all-lts-quantal
xserver-xorg-video-vmware-lts-quantal
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386
libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libllvm3.0:i386
libpciaccess0:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Comment: initialize build as given in this fourm 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/256487/initialising-the-build-environment-for-android-on-64-bit-12-04

Comment: Yes, I know exactly WHAT caused it (because it did it to me too) - the install of libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 wipes out most of X. WHY is another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have uninstalled quite a few important packages including `ubuntu-desktop` and `xorg`. This is the reason why you have no GUI. Still you have a shell running.

Before rebooting, switch to first terminal `CTRL+ALT+F1` Log on. Then run

```
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop xorg
```

Agree to remove `libgl1-mesa-dri`

Comment: @Grzeqorz: How is one supposed to remove libgl1-mesa-dri wihtout also removing ubuntu-dekstop or xorg? Seems like they are dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Simply re-installing the desktop using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` followed by a reboot worked for me.

Comment: maybe with usage of the `--reinstall` modifier?